# JQuery Tree Traversal : mixing closest and siblings

Tags: jquery, tree-traversal, closest, siblings, ancestor

I have structures that look like this :

```
<div class="wanted" id="but-not-really">
    <div class="wanted">
        <div class="dad">
            <input class="reference"/>
            <input class="wanted"/>
            <input class="bro3"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I want to get the width of either an ancestor (`div.wanted`) or a sibling (`input.wanted`) of my `.reference` element (which is `$(this)` in my JS loop), depending of which is the closest.

If I only wanted to seek through the ancestors, I would use `$(this).closest('.wanted').width()`.
If I only wanted to seek through the siblings, I would use `$(this).siblings('.wanted').width()`.

I tried to use `$(this).parents().find('.wanted').width()` but the webpage contains other elements up the document that are interfering. That's why I'm looking for the closest `.wanted` element among the siblings and the ancestors.

**SOLUTION N°1 (thanks to @undefined) :**

> At first check the siblings using `siblings` method, if the collection
>   is empty then use `closest`.

```
var width = $(this).siblings('.wanted').length === 0
             ? $(this).closest('.wanted').css('width')
             : $(this).siblings('.wanted').css('width');
```

Comment: You might have to manually iterate up and down the tree and keep a record of the 'degree of separation' to compare at the end of your loop. I don't know of any inbuilt jQuery function that will do this for you.

Comment: At first check the siblings using `siblings` method, if the collection is empty then use `closest`.

Comment: @undefined The question is the find the closest between ancestors and descendants, not which exists

Comment: What is `this` in your loop? Show your code.

Comment: @Satpal: `$(this)` is the `.reference` element. My code is a little complicated and not relevant for this question.

Comment: @undefined: I was hoping there was a JQuery function to avoid this. Anyway I came up with this solution : `var width = input.siblings(selector).length === 0 ? input.closest(selector).css('width') : input.siblings(selector).css('width');`

Comment: @SeevenByakko You can also define a method, something like `nearest`? Unfortunately jQuery doesn't have such method.

Comment: @undefined: Yes, it would be a useful JQuery method IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
var closestNextDistance = $(this).nextUntil('.wanted').length;
var closestPrevDistance = $(this).prevUntil('wanted').length;
var closestParentDistance = $(this).parentsUntil('.wanted').length;
```

Then compare the distances to check which one is the closest element, if the parent is closer, call

```
$(this).closest(selector).css('width')
```

else if one of the siblings is closer then call

```
$(this).prevAll('.wanted').css('width')
```

or

```
$(this).nextAll('.wanted').css('width')
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/3z7t5gqn/

You'll need to add few checks there to see if there's a next('.wanted') sibling when nextUntil returns 0 but if you turn it into a little function, you could re-use it.